# OpenBSD for ARMv7 does not support SMP

Tags: multicore, openbsd, smp

According to the home page [OpenBSD for ARMv7](http://www.openbsd.org/armv7.html), the kernel does not support SMP. Does this mean even if there are multiple cores in a CPU, only one core will work?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean even if there are multiple cores in a CPU, only one core will work?

Yes, multiple cores will not help for that fraction of processing that would otherwise benefit from parallel processing. SMP architecture applies to cores where each core is treated as a separate processor.